# Cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization using JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

my code have nest iframe ,I want to close parent Iframe when child iframe would be closed.But I got that error:cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close' .

Child Page:

> ```
>         {
>             text:"closethisAndIt'sParentIframe",click:function(){
>                 var temp = $(parent.window.document.getElementById("CreateDialog").outerHTML)[0];
>                 $(temp).dialog("close");
>                 $(this).dialog("close");
>             }
>         }
> ```

Parent Iframe:

> ```
>         $('<div id="CreateDialog"><iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="@Url.Action("AddRoleKInd","Role")" frameborder=0 /></div>').dialog({
>             autoOpen: true,
>             height: avaliHeight * 0.3,
>             position: { my: 'middle', at: 'middle', of: window, collision: 'fit' },
>             width: avaliWidth * 0.3,
>             beforeClose: function () {
>                 //TODO
>             }
>         })
> ```

So,How could I close the child iframe to close the parent Iframe at the same time?thanks.